# How to support ADD CONSTRAINTS in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm thinking of ADD CONSTRAINT to my db table as per example from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
```

However, discover from https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html, ADD CONSTRAINT is not supported by SQLite. What's the option I have (fyi, I'm developing in Android, and only have SQLite).

Comment: `create unique index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a unique constraint, just add a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_persons_pid_lastname ON PERSONS(P_Id, LastName);
```

It is curious that you would have a table called `Persons` and that `P_Id` would not already be unique in the table (by being a primary key).

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, Thanks! How about `ALTER TABLE mytable CONSTRAINT unique_hash UNIQUE (hash) ON CONFLICT REPLACE`. Can that still use `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX`?

Comment: The behavior would be different.  The unique index would prevent the insertion of a new row.  The `on conflict replace` would put the new row in, replacing the previous row.

Comment: I see. I posted my question in http://stackoverflow.com/q/40239021/3286489, if you have some idea on how to address that would help much. Thanks!!