# SQLite option for ADD CONSTRAINT with ON CONFLICT REPLACE

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite doesn't support Add Constaints. I have the below SQL. How could I get that supported?

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT unique_hash UNIQUE (hash) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

Note: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` won't solve this problem of having `ON CONFLICT REPLACE`

Comment: See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html#otheralter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support ADD CONSTRAINTS in SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238546/how-to-support-add-constraints-in-sqlite)

Comment: Not really. The previous answer doesn't help on when having CONFLICT REPLACE.